# Flutter Web Device Not Showing in Android Studio & VS Code

Tags: android, ios, flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-web

I am trying to develop a web app with flutter but my device is not showing there in IDE when i execute `flutter devices`

```
$ flutter devices
2 connected devices:

Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Brave Browser 78.1.0.1 unknown
Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
```

I could see two devices there but when i am using Andoid studio or vs code the browser is not showing up there
Thease are the screen shots from andoid studio and vs code
[image: ScreenShot From VS Code]
[image: ScreenShot From Android Studio]

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on Linux with the latest Flutter Beta 1.12.13+hotfix.6
Already spend a lot of time on this, not sure what to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Issue is solved by setting the path variable globally in my Linux
by editing the file `/etc/environment` by running

```sh
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

and then adding the line

```
CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

setting the `CHROME_EXECUTABLE=<path-to-chrome-chromium-or-brave>`
and restarting fixed my problem

Comment: I defined CHROME_EXECUTABLE in the .bashrc file and was wondering why it did not work. after I tried your solution and restarted the computer it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The answer above does work, but sometimes it doesn't. Especially for Linux distros have different ways of defining variables. However, what I found to be always working especially in ***manjaro*** are following:

- opening the file manager with root
- going to `/etc/profile.d`
- create a file, you can name it whatever you want, in this case we can name it `chrome.sh` (.sh is necessary)
- open the file and type the variable you want, with the export command
  (for example, i wanted to specify microsoft edge dev as the default chrome)

> export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/microsoft-edge-dev

- restart your pc, and you're done